# Laravel 5.5 require auth in staging

Tags: php, routes, laravel-middleware, laravel-5.5

I have a project with a few packages that have routes. I have a staging/demo environment that needs to be publicly accessible.

Is there a way to require the auth middleware (or something similar) for all routes without putting it on all of the individual routes and route groups? (Thinking something in bootstrap??)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a middleware to run during every HTTP request to your application, simply list the middleware class in the `$middleware` property of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` class.

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    YOUR MIDDLEWARE::class,
];
```

If you do not have access, or do not want, to modify the package controllers, you can create a Middleware (recommend inheriting from `AuthenticateSession`. For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession;

use Auth;
use Closure;

class AuthenticateIfEnvironment extends AuthenticateSession
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (env('APP_ENV') == 'XXXXXXXX' && !Auth::user() && !$request->is('login')) {
            return redirect('/login');
        }
        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }
}
```

Then `Kernal.php` looks like this:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateIfEnvironment::class,
];
```

Comment: Ran into a problem. Added the auth middleware there. Can't reach the /login route because, well, it's a route. The answer, as written, doesn't say, make your own route (though it is implied). Just want to make sure we're clear for future readers.

Comment: You can add the following line in your controller that handles login and logout (AuthController may be):                                                               `$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['getActivate', 'anotherMethod']]);`          inside the constructor.

Comment: Yeah. I don't wish to mess with the package controllers. Basically, these packages are "full service"; so, I think I would have to (want to) do what I can inside the main app bundle. See edits awaiting peer review.